# How do I run androidTest with product flavour enabled in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following product flavours and build types in my gradle file:

```
flavorDimensions "market"

productFlavors {
    amazon {
        dimension "market"
    }
    google {
        dimension "market"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
    }

    qa2 {
    }

    beta {
    }

    release {
    }
}
```

As expected my directory structure looks like:

[image: Project structure]

My problem is that when I hit run on androidTest in Android Studio 2.3.2 it will simply error out with

```
Class not found: "SomeClass" Empty test suite.
```

Comment: With no flavours it will prompt me to select the device and run simply run the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, only one *Build Type* is tested. By default, it is the `debug` *Build Type*, but this can be reconfigured with:

```
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "beta"
}
```

See more details at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide

Comment: That is a good tip but it does not solve my issue, testBuildType refers to the unit test's I need to solve the androidTest problem, but the link you gave me lead me to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Testing1 that might have some useful thing.

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved it was to postfix the `androidTest` with one of the flavor, let's say `Google` and changed the build variant to `GoogleDebug`

[image: Structure that works]